# Jquery get or post method not calling if input integer text is large?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am calling JQuery post method for that passing one integer value.If input value less than 9 calling the post method but if i am giving more input integer value as input not calling my controller post method.
Please tell me why the post method not calling if input integer text is large?

```
public ActionResult GetDetails(int id)
        {
        }

 $.post("<%=Url.Action("GetDetails", "ActionController")%>", { id: Id }, function (html) {

        Object = JSON.parse(html);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are going above Integer Length of C#

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx

Give a try as string or Long and see if it works fine or not.

If it works fine then issue is related to Int Length.